# What is the @ after directory listing mean?

Tags: ls

so I have some files in a directory and when I type `ls -l` I get

```
-rw-r--r--   1 home  staff   275 Apr  9 16:01 index.js
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 home  staff  2565 Apr  8 10:38 person.js
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 home  staff  4219 Apr  9 15:55 people.js
drwxr-xr-x  11 home  staff   374 Apr  9 15:43 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 home  staff   367 Apr  9 15:43 package.json
```

and I was wondering what the `@` means after the `person.js` and `people.js` permissions

Comment: Ever thought of doing `man ls`?

Comment: Which OS? What is the output of `type ls`?

Comment: `type ls` outputs `ls is hashed (/bin/ls)`

Answer (score 2):

That's system specific, `man ls` will tell you. On Apple OS/X for instance, that's to say the file has extended attributes.

Comment: It may not be in the manpage. With my GNU `ls`, a `+` at the end indicates POSIX extended attributes, but I can't find that in the actual documentation.

Comment: @jordanm, `man ls` for GNU ls tells you to continue reading with the `info page` where it's explained (and that's not for extended attributes, and AFAIK, POSIX doesn't specify extended attributes (though there once was a now-defunct draft that specified extended ACLs which you may be referring to))